# how to add broker id manually to zookper cli

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hdp

we have `kafka` cluster with 3 brokers machines 
and 3 `zookeeper` servers machines

all servers are installed on redhat 7.2 version

but when we run the following cli ( to know that all brokers ids are exist in zookeeper , we get:

```
zookeeper-shell.sh zoo_server:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids"

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[3, 2]
```

*instead to get that:*

```
[3, 2 , 1]
```

we checked the first broker ( `kafka01` ) by searching errors in `server.log`

And we not see any related error in the log!

port 2181 from kafka broker to zookeeper machine is working

we also restart `kafka01` , but this not help to get the broker id in zookeeper cli

we try also to restart all `zookeeper` servers ( there are 3 ) , and then again to restart `kafka01` , but still without results

**so any suggestion to this behavior?**

**can we add the missing broker to zookeeper cli ? , if yes then how?**

note - I see another thread - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Specified-config-does-not-exist-in-ZooKeeper/td-p/1875

but no info about how to add id to zookeeper

Comment: please let me know what logs you want , but as I said kafka01 is ok , not see any error from server.log , also on zookeeper server logs not see any error

Comment: kafka configuration is part in ambari ( kafka configuration in ambari is correct )

Comment: as I said all kafkla broker are the same configuration ( in ambari ) , the server.log not include any error , so why you not give attention to what I am saying?  , please be more specific?

Comment: That simply sounds like the `kafka01` server is simply not connected/configured with the rest of the cluster.  So, the "cluster" is really only brokers 2 and 3 right now.

Comment: in ambari - I see in kafka --> config three kafka , I not make any change , this behavior is in the last week , before that everything was ok

Comment: Is it possible that `zookeeper.connect` property on one of your Kafka servers specifies a different Zookeeper `chroot`?

Comment: we checked again but zookeeper.connect include all zoo servers

Comment: I'm actually talking about zk chroot, a specific node in global zk namespace under which kafka server will store all its data. Like `hostname-zk1:port1,hostname-zk2:port2,hostname-zk3:port3/chroot/path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is very simple

what we do is that

1. restart all zookeepers servres
2. restart all kafka servers

now we see all brokers ids